# CockroachDB: Why do I get the error "lastval is not yet defined in this session"?

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb

If have a SERIAL column on my table and insert a value, the column gets automatically populated but if I call `SELECT lastval()` to get the value afterwards, even though it's the same session, I get the error "lastval is not yet defined in this session". This works in Postgres but is an error in CockroachDB. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`lastval()` itself works the same in CockroachDB and Postgres--it returns the most recent value generated by `nextval()` in the same SQL session, and returns that error if it was never called. The difference is CockroachDB's default implementation of the SERIAL keyword. Postgres implements this by creating a sequence and implicitly calling nextval on it whenever you insert into the table. CockroachDB instead calls `unique_rowid()`, which is more performant but doesn't populate lastval. You can get compatible behavior by setting the `serial_normalization` variable to `virtual_sequence` before creating tables with SERIAL columns, and/or modifying existing serial columns to use a virtual sequence.

For example,

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dummy_seq VIRTUAL;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('dummy_seq');
```

Or you can avoid the extra trip to the database entirely by using a [RETURNING clause](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/insert.html#insert-and-return-values) on your insert.